# What are the prominent algorithms for solving systems of linear inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Why, you may ask?

The Python sympy symbolic library provides solutions to single, linear Diophantine equations in terms of parametric variables. For instance,

```
{(t_0, -9*t_0 - 5*t_1 + 154, -5*t_0 - 3*t_1 + 77)}
```

Without worrying about coding details, how can one solve such a system of parametric expressions for values of the original variables constrained to be, for instance, greater than zero.

Are there any opensource products?

Comment: [Sage can do this most likely](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/linear_programming.html), although integer linear programming is generally NP-hard.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I understand. I'm asking because I would like to offer an example involving only a small number of variables, for sympy.

Comment: Can you explain what the syntax of the example means? To me, this simply reads like a collection of linear expressions. How does it represent a system of linear inequalities?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Say the Diophantine equation were given in terms of x, y and z. Then one could make arbitrary choice of integers t_0 and t_1 and then one tuple of values for x, y and z would be given by that tuple in the set. I would like to be able to solve, for instance, for the system of inequalities where each item in the tuple is set >0.

Comment: So is there only one solution, or is it a whole region in space that satisfies these equations? Are you only interested in one feasible solution, or in characterizing the whole region?

Comment: I would like to be able to describe the entire collection of values of t_0 and t_1 that yield values of x, y and z whose values exceed 0 (say). Possible? For a Diophantine equation with just a very few variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a numerical answer, LP and MILP solvers can efficiently (not always for MIP) provide you with a feasible solution by optimizing an objective function of zeroes.